# python: why sorted does not sort correctly integers?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

```
a = {1: "one", 2:"two", 4:"four", 3:"three", 25:"twentyfive", 10:"ten", 8:"eight", 6: "six", 12:"Twelve"}
sorted(a)
```

Results in:

```
{1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three', 4: 'four', 6: 'six', 8: 'eight', 25: 'twentyfive', 10: 'ten', 12: 'Twelve'}
```

Why does 25 come before 10 and 12?

PS. I need this in a django template. I just want then in the template (using pyhaml), options being a dictionary:

```
                %div.options
                  Options:
                    - for key, value in options.items
                      //print the value
```

Comment: `sorted` returns a new iterable representing a sorted version of the iterable you pass in. It doesn’t modify the input, and iterating over a dict iterates over its keys. You can’t sort a dict in-place because dicts are unordered. *(This is also why the display order isn’t the same as in your literal.)* Consider `sorted_items = sorted(a.items())`, an iterable of (key, value) tuples.

Comment: `sorted(a)` never returns a dictionary as it gives you only the keys in order.

Comment: That isn't what I'd expect `sorted` to do to a dictionary. Are you using a function different to the built-in `sorted`?

Comment: I think the keys in your dict are strings not integers.

Comment: @minitech please provide your suggestion with items() as an anwer, that's what I finally need in my case

Comment: People downvoting just because they are experienced python users and thinking I am stupid? That's fine, but there's nothing wrong with the question really.

Answer (score 1):

Standard Python dictionaries are unordered. Even if you it, you wouldn't be able to store the value pairs in a dictionary in a way that would preserve the ordering.

You could use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) if you want to sort a dictionary by its keys, as has been suggested before in StackOverflow:

```
import collections
a = {1: "one", 2:"two", 4:"four", 3:"three", 25:"twentyfive", 10:"ten", 8:"eight", 6: "six", 12:"Twelve"}
sorted_a = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(a.items()))
print sorted_a
```

Which then prints:

```
OrderedDict([(1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three'), (4, 'four'), (6, 'six'), (8, 'eight'), (10, 'ten'), (12, 'Twelve'), (25, 'twentyfive')])
```